# How to change or create Lvm partition in Centos after install OS in shell

Tags: centos, lvm

How to change or create Lvm partition in Centos dedicate server after install OS in shell?

Comment: Um, use the LVM tools? `rpm -ql lvm` (or `rpm -ql lvm-tools` or `rpm -ql lvm2` or whatever the package is called) will show you a list of relevant tools, as will `apropos lvm`. Your question would be more useful if you told us what you want to do.

Comment: Hi dear friend
i want create it for virtualization,(with zen) and install hypervm.
my server have 2 Disk 750G...and 8G Ram..
after base installation(centos 5.7 x86_64) ..i changed disk one with this method :
1 - 200 MB EXT3 /boot
2 - 20 Gb EXT3 /
3 - 10 GB Swap
4 - End Of Space ( Linux LVM )
but after reboot ..my server Down.. ;(

Answer (score 1):

Using `lvcreate`/`lvextend`/etc. Exact command depends on what exactly you need to do.

Comment: **thanks dear..I want install xen-kernel ...**